# The recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=x_{n}+x_{n-1}+c\,(x_{n},\,x_{n-1})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to study the behaviour of the recurrence relation
$$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+x_{n-1}+c(x_{n},x_{n-1})\;\;\;\;\;\;\;c,x_{n} \in \mathbb Z$$
where $(x_{n},x_{n-1})$ is the gcd of $x_{n}$ and $x_{n-1}$.

If $c=0$ you obtain a Fibonacci-like recurrence relation.

If $c=1,\,x_{0}=1,\,x_{1}=1$ you obtain the following sequence
$$1,1,3,5,9,15,27,45,81,135,243,405,\dots$$
representable in closed form as

- $x_{n}=3^\frac{n}{2}\;$ if n is even
- $x_{n}=5\cdot3^\frac{n-3}{2}\;$ if n is odd and greater than 1
- $x_{n}=1\;$ if n=1

The given recurrence relation is connected to [those proposed on MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344652/investigating-the-recurrence-relation-x-n1-fracx-nx-n-1x-n-x)
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_{n}+x_{n-1}}{(x_{n},x_{n-1})}+c$$
I ask if there is a way to predict the behaviour of similar recurrence relations.

Comment: What is the $\text{gcd}$ of negative numbers?

Comment: (-21,6)=3 is the GREATEST common divisor of -21 and 6 ...